# Color information disappears when writing a result of 'grep --color=auto' into a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

When I do as below with an aliased grep(grep --color=auto)

```
echo abcde | grep 'ab'
```

it returns abcde (ab in red).

but

```
echo abcde | grep 'ab' >foo.txt
```

foo.txt has just abcde.

I guess my terminal shows ab in red in the 1st case according to some tags by 'grep' but foo.txt does not contain them. Is it due to grep?

Does grep judge what returning value should be?

My grep is grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep recognizes where you store the result and disables coloring in case of `auto` setting for redirections (colors is enabled only for terminal).

Use `--color=always` to force it to use it ... always, but I don't think you will find those control sequences nice to view in a text file.

Comment: Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 4):

With `--color=auto`, grep checks whether the output goes to a terminal, and switches colours on only when it does. You need to specify `--color=always` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much